# Do Wolverine's boneclaws cause self harm if his healing factor is absent?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine

Wolverine can retract his claws at will, but this involves them slicing through the tissue of his knuckles. But we know that he has an abnormal healing factor which may account for why he is unscathed when he does this.

If he loses this healing counterpart of his overall ability does this mean that subsequent uses of his bone claws will leave him with knuckles both bloody and with noticeable slits?

Comment: like Wolverine said to Rogue in X-Men 1 "it hurts everytimes" !
and if wolverines ability to heal becomes like a normal human beeing well what do you think will happen if anything pierces his skin... including his own claws :P

Comment: I remember a page of Wolverine with bone claws and a compromised healing factor talking to another mutant. His hands are covered with bandages. He impales a butterfly on a claw, saying something like that he likes to keep the wounds open. Unfortunately, I don't know what issue of which series this should be, but there should be material out there.

Comment: In the animated series, when they were in the Savage Land and their powers were suppressed, he grunted in pain each time, and there were holes left.

Comment: In the animated series, the holes looked like they had adamantium plating.

Comment: 1)Wolverine still feels pain.
2)If Wolverine were to loose his healing ability and extend and retracts his claws, then yes, he would still have holes in his hands where they entered/exited his skin.  Not really sure why this is even a question as it's common sense.

Answer (score 4):

[image: .]

The short answer is yes. 
This page is from Wolverine issue 75 from 1993 and shows the first time Wolverine pops his bone claws. When Magneto ripped the adamantium from Logan's bones it also burned out his healing factor